# How do I hook up javascript to my CustomValidator control in .Net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, custom-validators

I have created a CustomValidator control

```
public class MyValidator :CustomValidator, IScriptControl {}
```

and also created the equivalent client script.  The server validation works fine, however how do I hook up my client script?

The rendered javascript looks like

```
var MyValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["MyValidator1"] : document.getElementById("MyValidator1");
MyValidator1.controltovalidate = "MyField";
MyValidator1.errormessage = "error";
MyValidator1.evaluationfunction = "MyValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
```

How do I override the generated javascript to set the value of evaluationfunction?  E.g.

```
MyValidator1.evaluationfunction = "MyCustomJavascriptFunction";
```

Comment: Yes. You can see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this myself as the other answer didn't quite achieve exactly what I wanted.  I ended up using.

```
public class MyValidator : BaseValidator, IScriptControl  {

  protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
    base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(this.ClientID, "evaluationfunction", "MyJavascriptFunction");
  }

}
```

Which will cause the control to generate:

```
MyValidator1.evaluationfunction = "MyJavascriptFunction";
```

Comment: I tried this but ASP.Net complained the attribute was already added. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ClientValidationFunction property of the base class like this -

```
base.ClientValidationFunction = "MyCustomJavascriptFunction";
```

So, it will render it like this -

```
MyValidator1.evaluationfunction = "MyCustomJavascriptFunction";
```

You can do it from the control also by setting the same property.

EDIT: You can do

```
document.getElementById("<%= ValidatorId %>").evaluationfunction = "MyCustomJavascriptFunction";
```

Comment: Doing this adds the line 
MyValidator1.clientvalidationfunction = MycustomJavascriptFunction";
Is there a way to set MyValidator1.evaluationfunction?

Answer (score 1):

Actually much easier is to use the ClientValidationFunction property of the asp:CustomValidator like below. Be sure NOT to specify a ControlToValidate property.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ClientValidationFunction="MyCustomJSFunction" Text="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>

function MyCustomJSFunction(validator, args) {
    args.IsValid = my condition;
}
```