# Developing ASP.NET validator with client-side validation

Tags: asp.net

How to define client-side logic in new ASP.NET validator (not CustomValidator). Can you point me to articles where whole process is described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultipleFieldsValidator.aspx) goes through the process of creating a new custom validator by deriving from `BaseValidator` instead of `CustomerValidator`.

The trick for getting ASP.NET to execute your JS code is this (in `AddAttributesToRender()`):

```
if(this.RenderUplevel) {
    string clientID = this.ClientID;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(clientID, 
        "evaluationfunction", 
        "MultipleFieldsValidatorEvaluateIsValid");
}
```

ASP.NET will then call `MultipleFieldsValidatorEvaluateIsValid()`.

Also, see [How do I hook up javascript to my CustomValidator control in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792858/how-do-i-hook-up-javascript-to-my-customvalidator-control-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.NET MVC world, there's a wonderful validation framework called [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/), which I have used with great success. Apparently there is a port for ASP.NET, [xVal for WebForms](http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/). I have not used it, but it might be worth a try. Good luck!